# PHP: How to get all tags inside certain tag in XML by means of DOM extension

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have XML

```
<myelement>
    <oneelement>val1</<oneelement>
    <notknown>val2</notknown>
    <notknown2>val3</notknown2>
</myelement>
```

and I parse it. I get one xml-tag:

```
$myelement=$reask->getElementsByTagName('myelement')->item(0)
```

Now I want get all tags inside $myelement even I don't know their names. How could I do this if I use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension of PHP5?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the childNodes property of `$myelement` as described in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes):

```
$childrenOfmyelement = $myelement->childNodes;
```